# php, regex preg_match a specific word 0 or 1 time

Tags: php, regex, pattern-matching, match

I want to match a string with the words of another string, keeping the order:

```
$string_original = "Number three is good, then two and one.";
$match_string = "three two one";
$result = magic_function($string_original,$match_string);
```

I want the result to be

```
$result = array(0 => 'three', 1 => 'two', 2 => 'one');
```

Because all the words in the match string are found in the original ordered.
An other example:

```
$string_original = "two is a magic number, one also and three";
$match_string = "three two one";
$result = magic_function($string_original,$match_string);
//RESULT WOULD BE
$result = array(0 => 'three');

//LAST EXAMPLE
$string_original = "three one, then two!";
$match_string = "three two one";
$result = magic_function($string_original,$match_string);
//RESULT WOULD BE
$result = array(0 => 'three', 1 => 'two');
```

My magic_function is something like

```
function magic_function($origin,$match){
$exploded = explode(' ',$match);
$pattern = '/';
foreach ($exploded as $word){
$pattern .= '';//I NEED SOMETHING TO PUT HERE, BUT MY REGEX IS PRETTY BAD AND I DON'T KNOW
}
$pattern .= '/';
preg_match($pattern,$origin,$matches);
return $matches;
}
```

Any help with the regex part? Thank you.

Comment: we dont respond well to request to simply write the code for you.

Comment: @Dagon I wrote the whole code, I just need help with a regexp that I cannot figure out. It's an easy request, not a whole script...

Comment: well it its easy then ...

Comment: Just in case... http://ideone.com/7ehj3D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using [`preg_split`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php) instead of `preg_match`. Also make sure to escape words you search for with [`preg_quote`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-quote.php). I also suggest adding word boundary conditions (`\b`) to the regular expressions, so you only match complete words. Take that out if you want to match part of words:

```
function magic_function($string_original,$match_string) {
    foreach(explode(' ', $match_string) as $word) {
        $word = preg_quote($word);
        $split = preg_split("/\b$word\b/", $string_original, 2);
        if (count($split) < 2) break;
        $result[] = $word;
        $string_original = $split[1];
    }
    return $result;
}
```